# unit testing with sinon framework

Tags: unit-testing, sinon

I am new to unit testing , I want to check whether a function has called using sinnon . I have  a function as below.

```
function average(a,b){
 return (a+b)/2;
}
```

I try to check with the sinon.spy() method. But I could not understand where I should use sinon.spy() to check whether this function has called or not. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sinon is a library for creating mocks, stubs and spies. You need to use it within a testing framework such as Karma (http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) or JSTestDriver (https://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/).

Comment: I'm using mocha framework for this testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var spy = sinon.spy(average);
var result = spy(5,3);
expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
expect(result).to.equal(4);
```

this test will give 1 passes and 0 failures.